# Is there a way to open a Visual Studio Code internal powershell window from NPM Script?

Tags: powershell, npm, visual-studio-code

I am currently doing some work with npm scripts and can't find an answer to my question online!

I want to run 3 NPM scripts by typing one command. Here the scripts:

`"start-jsonserver:platform": "ng serve --configuration jsonserver"`

`"start:corePlugins": "ng serve corePlugins",`

`"start:jsonserver": "cd ../json-server & npm run start",`

`"start:allJsonEnvironment": "npm run start-jsonserver:platform && npm run start:corePlugins && npm run start:jsonserver",`

Note that the last command is not working as I want it to as it stops after the first `ng serve` is "done". I have also tried the same command with just one `&` but this has the same effect

I have found a solution which is opening 3 seperate Powershell windows:

`"start:allJsonEnvironment": "start powershell npm run start-jsonserver:platform && start powershell npm run start:corePlugins && start powershell npm run start:jsonserver"`

The Problem is this opens the normal 'standalone' Powershell windows which, to be honest is really ugly and I am used to seeing the VS Code internal **Powershell** windows (3 at the same time) since its easy to spot if something went wrong.
Like that:

[image]

So if there is a way to open these 'internal' Powershell windows from the npm script I would really appreciate help.

(I know there is a way to run all three scripts in one internal window but that is not what I am looking for!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after some research I have found another solution.

Its not envolving NPM scripts but it is actually the better solution.

My personal solution to the Problem was to use the VS Code Tasks and `dependsOn` to connect all three commands:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": 
        [
        {
            "label": "corePlugins",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend"
            },
            "command": "ng serve corePlugins"
        },
        {
            "label": "serve_conf_json",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend"
            },
            "command": "ng serve --configuration jsonserver"
        },
        {
            "label": "json-server",
            "group": "test",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/json-server"
            },
            "command": "npm run start"
        },
        {
            "label": "startAllJson",
            "dependsOn": [
                "json-server",
                "corePlugins",
                "serve_conf_json",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So now I can just run the Task `startAllJson` and it opens 3 VSCode Terminals and runs those commands.

I know this might not be the perfect answer to my question but it was the best solution I found in a short amount of time.